# SQL query to variable in powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, mcafee

There is my script:

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=xxxxx;Database=xxxx;User ID=xxxx\xxxx;Password=xxxxx;Trusted_Connection=True;"
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT version FROM xxxx.dbo.EPOAvertContentUpdates where productId=VSCANDAT1000"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$dbname = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
$SqlConnection.Close()
Write-output "version" $dbname
```

The error what I get:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteScalar" with "0" argument(s): "ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."
At line:12 char:1
+ $results = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

I want to get the product ID number from our database, and store it to variable to comapre it with other variable. Any suggestion what is the problem? 
Thanks for the help!

@vonPryz: the connection state Open

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What's the result if you execute `$SqlConnection.state` after calling `.Open()`? Please add this to the question, don't post as a comment as those are hard to read.

Comment: Is there any way, that you are only reusing the `$SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()` without executing/opening the connection again? e.g. you only executed the 4th to 6th line. Just an observation since in your error it shows as `$results` instead of your posted code which is `$dbname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue speculation:
You executed the posted script snippet once, and then just re-executed the lines and changed the variable to `$results`:

```
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT version FROM xxxx.dbo.EPOAvertContentUpdates where productId=VSCANDAT1000"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
```

But this time for another database?

When executing any other TSQL, please make sure to open the SQL connection first, execute the TSQL, and then close it.

Comment: Thanks the $results solved the problem. I got the correct result what I needed, also I made some changes in my script with the suggestions in this post.